How can I open a .DOTX or .DOCX file in C++ and edit it using key-value fields? Which free or paid library could I use? Thanks in advance
I need to edit template fields by key-value from C++ by opening the .DOTX or .DOCX file. So that I can change the data in the file to whatever I want. For example: in the file will appear {field} I want to change that "field" to "gas" for example. And when I save the file my new fields will appear.

I won't post an answer, since you specify C++. I find this easy enough to do in Python (and I suppose that you could call a python script from c++ easilly enough).   Take a look at  Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, especially   WORKING WITH PDF AND WORD DOCUMENTS.  It used the docx library

There is a library in Java called docx4j, you might be able to compile that as a library (that does exactly what you want) and link to it from your cpp.
If your use is really just as simple as find/replace, and you don't want to try the dirty Java hack, you can simply unzip the file (a docx is merely a zip file containing content and metadata files) and find/replace your tokens and zip it back up again.
For zipping, look at the boost iostreams library, or call libgzip or zlib from an API.

You should include a link to the site.

https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j
